# Is there a way to reset the values of a list in python?

Tags: python, list, reset

I'm working on a tic-tac-toe game that functions by replacing hyphens in a list with X's and O's to form a grid. I'm also a beginner when it comes to python, so this code is going to be clunky. The issue is that I want the game to be re-playable, but I can't find a way to reset the list to the hyphens I had at the start. Here's a simplified bit of code that better illustrates the problem:

```
list = ["-","-","-", "X","O"]

def replace():
    list[0] = list[3]

def main():
    replace()
    play_again = input ("play again?")
    if play_again == "yes":
        main()
    else:
        exit()
    
main()
```

This makes the list go from `["-","-","-", "X","O"]` to `["X","-","-", "X","O"]`, which makes the game work.

What I'd like to be able to do is somehow turn `list` back into `["-","-","-", "X","O"]` when the player plays again. Unfortunately, the list seems to be stuck at `["X","-","-", "X","O"]` . I've tried:

1. adding `list = ["-","-","-", "X","O"]` right above `replace()`
2. adding `list[0] = "-"` right above `replace()`

and neither of these options work.

Is it possible to reset the values of `list` to what I had at the start? If so, how should I approach this?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name.  `list` is an important builtin that is blocked when you do it.

Comment: @user120242 That didn't seem to work, I got the local variable 'list' referenced before assignment error if I try to access the list (i.e. using print(list) ) in main()

Comment: @Tom Karzes I know, my variable in my actual code is gridlist. However, even if I change the variable name to something like gridlist, the potential solutions don't work.

Comment: Right, my comment was a general suggestion, not related to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest change that makes your code "work" is:

```
def main():
    global list
    list = ["-","-","-", "X","O"]
    replace()
    play_again = input ("play again?")
    if play_again == "yes":
        main()
    else:
        exit()
```

(Though that's not how I would do this from scratch--but you've already indicated that clunky code is okay/expected, so I'm not going to try and fix it here.)

This will also work, and doesn't require the `global` declaration:

```
def main():
    list[:] = ["-","-","-", "X","O"]
    replace()
    play_again = input ("play again?")
    if play_again == "yes":
        main()
    else:
        exit()
```

Comment: Yep, that fixes the problem! Would you mind sharing how you would do it?